# Why is `displayMenu` not defined here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following code:

```
import time
users = {}
status = ""
#import time module setup new Dictionary
#define mainMenu function
def mainMenu():
    displayMenu = mainMenu
    global status
    status = input("Do you have a login account? y/n? Or press q to quit.")
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()
    elif status == "q":
        quit()
#define newUser function
def newUser():
    createLogin = input("Create a login name: ")
    if createLogin in users:
        print ("\nlogin anem already exists!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw
        print("\nUser created!\n")
        logins=open("E:\Python_Docs\login_Py\logins.txt","a")
        logins.write("\n" + createLogin + " " + createPassw)
        logins.close()
#define oldUser function
def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

#check if user exists and login matches password
    if login in users and users [login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
        print("User:", login, "accessed the system on:", time.asctime())
    else:
        print ("\nUser doesn´t exist or wrong password!\n")

while status != "q":
    status = displayMenu
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Programmieren\python übungen\OwnCode.py", line 41, in <module>
status = displayMenu
NameError: name 'displayMenu' is not defined
```

Why is this? I tried:

```
def mainMenu():
    displayMenu = mainMenu
```

Why does this not define `displayMenu` as required?

Comment: You've defined `displayMenu` in a different function, which is a different scope. You need to define it inside the function where you're using it.

Comment: You defined it *locally* in another function. If you want access to it in another function, you need to pass it as an argument (recommended), or make it a global variable.

Comment: Is it possible, to close this question, because I can an useful answer and I would write my next question better, and hope that´s it not putting on-hold again?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing a variable in the scope of your function

Here is a new way to do your mainMenu function, and then call it at the end

```
import time
users = {}
#import time module setup new Dictionary
#define mainMenu function
def mainMenu():
    status = ""
    while status != "q":
        status = input("Do you have a login account? y/n? Or press q to quit.")
        if status == "y":
            oldUser()
        elif status == "n":
            newUser()
            break
        elif status == "q":
        quit()


#define newUser function
def newUser():
    createLogin = input("Create a login name: ")
    if createLogin in users:
        print ("\nlogin anem already exists!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw
        print("\nUser created!\n")
        logins=open("E:\Python_Docs\login_Py\logins.txt","a")
        logins.write("\n" + createLogin + " " + createPassw)
        logins.close()

#define oldUser function
def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

#check if user exists and login matches password
    if login in users and users [login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
        print("User:", login, "accessed the system on:", time.asctime())
    else:
        print ("\nUser doesn´t exist or wrong password!\n")


displayMenu = mainMenu()
```